# Rails 5, Factory Bot and Paperclip can't find file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't figure out how to give a file in one of my Factories. I'm using the default test suite of rails 5, Factory Bot, and Paperclip. This is the test I'm running:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AttachmentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should be valid" do
    p "should look into: #{ActionController::TestCase.fixture_path}"
    ressource = build(:attachment)
    assert ressource.valid?
  end
end
```

This is my fixture:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :attachment do
    file { fixture_file_upload('files/invoice.pdf', 'application/pdf') }
    association :attachable, factory: :mission
  end
end
```

I've `invoice.pdf` in `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/fixtures/files` (both values copy / pasted here directly from terminal)

The trace I get

```
# Running:

"should look into: /Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/fixtures/"
E

Error:
AttachmentTest#test_should_be_valid:
RuntimeError: files/invoice.pdf file does not exist
  test/factories/attachments.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  test/models/attachment_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:AttachmentTest>'


bin/rails test test/models/attachment_test.rb:5
```

I'm missing something but can't figure out what. As I'm using FactoryBot, does it change the fixtures/files path? How could I know it?

**Edit**
Try to move the invoice to this places:

- `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/fixtures/files/invoice.pdf`
- `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/factories/files/invoice.pdf`
- `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/files/invoice.pdf`
- `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/files/invoice.pdf`

Comment: Just use an absolute path instead of relative. `Rails.root.join('test', 'files', 'invoice.pdf')` would point to `/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/files/invoice.pdf` for example.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did until I find a better solution, but still waiting for something better. If I change the folder I would have to change it in every file, what is not optimum.